# Chrome extension listener not triggering on event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I am currently working on a Chrome extension that needs to capture and print the First and Last Name fields when a user registers on a certain webpage.

However, I am facing an issue where the listener for the registration event is not being triggered, and nothing appears in the console when the registration button is clicked.

I have already checked my manifest file and background script for any errors, and I'm not seeing any error messages in the console.

**Here is the relevant portion of my manifest file:**

```
{
  "name": "My extention",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Print user first+last name to the console",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

**Here is the relevant portion of my background.js file:**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.url.includes("https://www.example.com/register/") {
      const form = new FormData(details.requestBody.formData);
      const userFirstName = form.get('firstName');
      const userLastName = form.get('LastName');
      console.log(`FirstName: ${userFirstName}, LastName: ${userLastName}`);
    }
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"] },
  ["requestBody"]
);
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're still making manifest v2 extensions? That won't last long I think.